# How to disable overlapping tabs or scrolling tabs in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Sublime Text 3 has a default feature which makes tabs overlap each other instead of the old behavior where the horizontal length of the tab would shrink. How do you disable this?

Comment: Did you get this from http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=15082 ?

Comment: No. I found it by searching for "tab" in Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings - Default.

Comment: It took me a while to realize that the tab here is in the sense like the tab of a browser, not a tab character `\t` or the `Tab` key

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In *Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings - User*, add the following line.

```
"enable_tab_scrolling": false,
```

Comment: When I do this, The tab size is becoming very small when I have multiple tabs. How can enable this and also make sure that the individual tab size is not reduced when multiple tabs are present?