# In Sublime, what do the left/right arrow buttons do in the top left of the interface?

Tags: sublime-text-2, user-interface, sublime-text-3

I know it sounds like a stupid question, but clicking them does nothing noticeable, and I can't find any info after googling it.

Comment: You say you think your question sounds stupid, but SHOW A PIC (otherwise it is a stupid question). I have ST2 and don't see them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable overlapping tabs or scrolling tabs in Sublime Text 3](http://superuser.com/questions/698212/how-to-disable-overlapping-tabs-or-scrolling-tabs-in-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two tab display modes in Sublime Text 3. Layer and shrink. Those arrows are part of the layer setting.

You can use the arrows to scroll, for example:

[image]

and after clicking a few times:

[image]

You can also:

- Scroll the tabs with the mouse wheel.
- Hold down your click for continued scrolling.
- Use the downward arrow to open a dropdown list of tabs.
- **Note:** The arrows and mouse wheel don't take effect until there are enough tabs to scroll through.
- **Note:** Scrolling will not open the tabs automatically like shrink mode will.

To disable:

- In your user settings, add `"enable_tab_scrolling": false`. This will revert the display to shrink. And you can open the tabs by scrolling with the mouse wheel.

Comment: Thank you! Trying to find a setting to disable them now, but I don't think there is one…

Comment: @MarcusPlimsoll in your user settings, add `"enable_tab_scrolling": false`. This will cause the individual tabs to shrink as more are added, instead of scrolling them at full size.

Comment: @MattDMo II want to still scroll with my mouse wheel, but just have more space (no arrows), but I'll try this for a while. Thanks!

Comment: There are *three* synonymous key bindings to switch active tab left/right: `Super + Shift + [ or ]`, `Super + Alt + Left or Right`, and `Ctrl + Pagedown or Pageup`. Use `"command": "prev_view"` and `"command": "next_view" ` to create your own. Honestly, the UI buttons are a poor design decision - hide them to save space and reduce visual clutter.